# Simple bijective map from upper half plane to whole plane

Tags: complex-analysis, geometry

What is a simple bijective map from the upper half plane to the whole plane?

(Either the complex plane or $\mathbb{R}^2$ can do.)

I think it can be done via a map from upper half plane to unit disc and then from the disc to the whole plane.  But is there a simpler example that can be constructed?

====== Addendum ======

For the complex plane.  The map from upper half plane to unit disc is:
$$ f(z) = \frac{z - i}{z + i}  $$
The map from the unit disc to whole plane is:
$$ g(z) = \frac{z}{1-\left|z\right|^2} $$
So the composite map is:
$$ g \circ f(z) = \frac{(z-i) / (z+i)}{1-\left|(z-i)/(z+i)\right|^2} $$
But that looks complicated and I don't know how to simplify it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about $(x,y) \to (x,\ln y)$?

Comment: Not bad, but not a rational map :)

Comment: How about $(x,y)\to (x,y-1/y)$ for a rational map?

Comment: That's discontinuous at y = 0.  But thanks for it, I didn't require continuous.

Comment: Also, for the inverse map, you get a quadratic equation with 2 solutions, so it's not a function.

Comment: Oh, I made a mistake, only the positive half domain is needed, so your second example is also good :)